# Angular - Setting value of input has no effect

Tags: angularjs

Im trying to set a value of a password input field from the controller but its having no effect

Controller

```
$scope.passwordDetails.currentPassword = 'madeuppassword';

.
```

View

```
<div class="form-group" show-errors>
      <label for="currentPassword">Current Password</label>
      <input type="password" id="currentPassword" name="currentPassword" class="form-control"
             ng-model="passwordDetails.currentPassword" placeholder="Current Password" required>
      <div ng-messages="passwordForm.currentPassword.$error" role="alert">
        <p class="help-block error-text" ng-message="required">Your current password is required.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Is there something simple im doing wrong?

Comment: The code looks fine and should work. Did you forget to instantiate the controller (either <ANY ng-controller="..."></ANY>, or via a route)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `passwordDetails` is not initialized from before, your assignment on the scope should throw an error. In case you need the object, then try like this:

```
$scope.passwordDetails = {
    currentPassword: 'changeme'
};
```

Here's a working plnkr of your example: http://plnkr.co/edit/J3OfG0ioDJ85egoqTxSG?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

add the below line before assigning value to nested object.

```
$scope.passwordDetails = {};
$scope.passwordDetails.currentPassword = 'madeuppassword';
```